# what is rand algorithim depending on srand and seed?

Tags: c, random, entropy, random-seed

When I running this code

```
while ...
 srand (1);
 printf ("Again the first number: %d\n", rand()%100);
```

on 2 PCs I get different results. but in each PC I get always the same random list.

For ex. in PC 1 I always get `83,86,77,15,93,35` and in PC2 I always get `F, G ,H , I ,J`.

I want to know what is the algorithim? If I know the first random , is there any way to know the second random in same PC? .

Second random is depending on seed or only on the last random?

I not to put `srand(time(0));` to get a really random number , that not my problem, I only want to know if the second random number depending on input of `srand` +the first random number or not .

Comment: I don't understand this close vote. How does this question ask for an *off-site resource*?

Comment: What are the specific configurations of PC 1 and PC2? In particular, what operating system (including version) is each running, which compiler (including version) was used to compile the program for each system, and which run-time library (if not the compiler or operating system default) was each using? Also, please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of source code that produces the different results on the different systems.

Answer (score 1):

A PRNG (*pseudo random number generator*) is actually some deterministic calculation that calculates the next value from some internal state, updating this state as well. So, the numbers only *look* random, and starting from the same internal state, you get the same sequence of numbers.

The following part isn't needed any more after the question was edited, leaving it here for reference:

---

*Seeding* a PRNG initializes this internal state. Therefore you should *seed* **only once in your program**.

If you seed with a fixed value, you get the same sequence in every run, which might be good for testing.

For your final program, seed with something that will be different on every run. The typical line in a C program is

```
srand(time(0));
```

which uses the current time for seeding. You need `#include <time.h>` to do this.

---

> If I know the first random , is there any way to know the second random in same PC?

In general, no. As explained above, a *good* PRNG uses additional internal state, or, put the other way around, only returns *part* of its state as the "random number".

Here's a very simple example implementation:

```
static unsigned long long int randval = 1;

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    randval = seed;
}

int rand(void)
{
    randval *= 1103515245;
    randval += 12345;
    return (int)((randval / 65536) & 0x7fffffff);
}
```

Your C library probably has something more sophisticated, but it helps to understand the concept: The internal state here is `long long` (which has at least 64 bits), but `rand()` only ever returns 31 bits of it.

Comment: I know how to put `srand(time(0));` to really random number , I looking for the algo (if is there ??) to find the next random number , if is depending only on the last random +the input of srand or it depending on another thing

Comment: As I said, implementations typically have *internal state* (more than just the last number). There are many algorithms for PRNGs. [here's a simple one I did a while ago](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/stdlib/stdlib_rand.c). Which one is used in your case entirely depends on your C standard library, the algorithm isn't specified by the C standard.

Comment: I looking for the windows algo , in my pc I get `83,86,77,15,93,35`

Comment: There's no such thing as "*the windows algo*". There are many different C standard libraries. Microsoft has the old `msvcrt.dll` and delivers updated standard libraries with every new release of visual studio. There are also other standard libraries like `glibc` available on windows. If you need to know the algorithm, you should explain the reason (you won't know it, and you shouldn't need to).

Comment: @devohourse you may want to take a look at Linear Congruence Method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) or read volume 2 of "The Art of Computer Programming" by Donald Knuth for a detailed discussion of PRNG calculations

Answer (score -4):

The algorithm is determined by the library ,
In most(if not all) cases the function that produced the resulting numbers are dependent on the program heap+stack memory address , so in your case the results are not different from one pc to another but from one location in ram to another, every new random generated is dependent upon the last random number and sometimes the seed value also involved in the calculation (prefered), only the first number is calculated only with the seed value.

Comment: Do you have a single example of a PRNG working this way? Addresses *might* be used to further modify the seed, but using them in the "random" number calculation itself would risk to give some very strange distribution. Also, "*every new random generated is dependent upon the last random number, only the first number is calculated with the seed value.*" is wrong for a good PRNG, because you could get from one number only ever to the same next number -> not good.

Comment: "Modify the seed" is part of the calculation, atleast thats what i meant, and you right every new random is dependent on the last number and sometimes also on the seed, but it is not a demand and he did not ask about a "good" implementation, i explained only the basics..

Comment: Let's face it, it's just wrong. And revenge votes aren't in the spirit of stackoverflow.

Comment: What in my answer is wrong?.. the main issue the op wanted to understand is how come he gets different number sequence in other pc and if the generated number depends on the last number, you "explained" in you answer stuff that is not relevant, you should understand the question before answering, i did not vote down as you probably did as i understand from your ugly comment

Comment: 1.) there's no evidence addresses are used *at all*, and this would break [7.22.2.2 p2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2p2) of the C standard, which guarantees a predictable sequence with the same seed value 2.) your explanation about "the seed value also being used" is *cloudy* at best.

Comment: 1.here is stdlib's implementation:   https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/random_r.c.html#__random_r using ADDRESES 2.Its cloudy because it's not a rule! and there is no single explanation.

Comment: Your example doesn't use an address anywhere in the calculations. And yes, an implementation using only the last random number would suffice the requirements of the C standard, but even the minimal example given in the standard has more state.

Comment: No that does not use the address as a source in the calculation.

Comment: This line just adds values from the random table used in this function.

Comment: Do you have a different explanation to why he got different lists in different pcs?

Comment: Different runtime libraries sounds like a likely cause.

Comment: Either that or indeed an implementation that uses something machine-specific in `srand()`. The standard doesn't say anything about different machines, only "*If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1*"