# Does rand() indeed produce a random value when the random number generator has been seeded?

Tags: c, random, random-seed

I know that in order to avoid repeating the same output of the `rand()` function a pseudo-random number generator must be seeded with the `srand` function. That means, if I try say `srand(1)`, the output of the `rand()` will be one value, if I try `srand(2)`, the output will contain another value. But when I try the first argument again like `srand(1)`, the value will be the same as in the first output. This issue made me think that all random values would be predictable in some way. Is it possible to have different output for the same seed (say if I try the same seed tomorrow)? Or are random values predictable indeed?

Comment: For a given seed value, `rand()` will always produce the same sequence of numbers. As [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand), "Each time rand() is seeded with srand(), it must produce the same sequence of values."

Comment: @FredLarson so hypothetically I may memorise each value for each seed and predict the output?

Comment: If your memory is that good, yes.

Comment: @FredLarson well then random is not random at all, it looks more like a mere function of an argument which returns a particular value

Comment: That is why it is called 'pseudorandom'

Comment: No, it's not random. It's *pseudo-random*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is rand algorithim depending on srand and seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651185/what-is-rand-algorithim-depending-on-srand-and-seed)

Comment: @FredLarson the post is more about predictability rather than about mechanisms

Comment: It is convenient that the same sequence can be repeated on each run when debugging. While developing, I don't use `srand(time())` to set the seed value, because when the program misfires, it is very hard to replicate the situation. A truly random number generator would make it impossible to recreate the exact conditions (unless you had logged every value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the traditional definition of a pseudorandom generator, if you know what the generator has been seeded with, then the sequence of output values is completely determined and not random. This means that if you knew the seed for a random generator, then you could predict every single output that generator would produce from that point forward. (A good random number generator is one where seeing a sequence of outputs of the generator does not let you easily reverse-engineer what the random seed is or predict other values.)

I seem to remember reading a while back that, a while back, some popular poker websites were not doing a good job choosing their random seeds. Some people figured out that you could input the pattern of cards you were seeing, and the system could then reverse-engineer the random seed and let you predict all the future cards. Oops. These days, we have cryptographically secure pseudorandom generators based on encryption routines that, at least when it comes to what's known in the open literature, can't be predicted even if you have gigabytes of random bits of output from the generators.

If you do need to get something that really isn't predictable - that is, you want to get a bunch of truly random bits - you'll need to use something other than a pseudorandom number generator. Most operating systems have some mechanism in place to generate values that do appear to be truly random. They might, for example, look at how long it takes for different capacitors to discharge on the motherboard, or factor in timing information from a clock, or see how the user interacts with the keyboard, etc. These data can be fed into something called an ***entropy accumulator*** that slowly builds up more and more random bits. If you need a value that's truly random and can't be predicted in advance, you can check your particular OS for the mechanism used to get data from the entropy accumulator. (You can read from `/dev/random` on UNIX-style machines, for example.)

Often, pulling data from the entropy accumulator takes time, since the computer has to wait long enough for enough different sources to mix together to give you back high-quality random data. A common strategy, therefore, is to use the entropy accumulator to get a high-quality random seed, then "stretch" the randomness by using it as the seed of a strong pseudorandom generator.

Comment: Thanks, that is a poor show for `rand()` :) Could you please answer why they talk about a _sequence_ when my output only contains one value?

Comment: @Kaiyaha, it is rare that an application relying on (pseudo-)random numbers only wants one.  You get a sequence of such numbers by calling `rand()` multiple times (after seeding it only once).

Comment: The seed just give a starting point.  After it is seeded, you can keep calling it and it will result in seemingly random values.

Comment: @JohnBollinger well and do you know how many values are there in this sequence?

Comment: @Kaiyaha The sequence itself goes on forever - you can just keep calling `rand()`. How long it is before the sequence repeats itself depends on the particular random number generator, and I don't believe that's specified by the spec.

Comment: @templatetypedef I assumed it would be the same length as the value of `RAND_MAX`

Comment: @Kaiyaha, the generator's period does not need to be the same as `RAND_MAX`.  It could easily be either greater or less.  The C language specifications put no requirements on that.  If you have specific requirements for the properties of a PRNG, then you would be well advised to choose or write an implementation whose properties you know.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is simply the largest value that can be generated.  The sequence of numbers is generated by a mathematical function.  Call the function again and you get the next value in the sequence.  You can keep calling this function as many times as you like, but as stated, it may eventually reach a point where it repeats the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Here is  the language of the C Standard:

> **7.22.2 Pseudo-random sequence generation functions**
>
> **7.22.2.1 The `rand` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>  #include <stdlib.h>
>  int rand(void);
> ```
>
> The `rand` function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`
> The `rand` function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the `rand` function.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `rand` function returns a pseudo-random integer.
>
> **Environmental limits**
>
> The value of the `RAND_MAX` macro shall be at least 32767.
>
> **7.22.2.2 The `srand` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void srand(unsigned int seed);
> ```
>
> The `srand` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand`. If `srand` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when `srand` is first called with a seed value of 1.
>
> The `srand` function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the `srand` function.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `srand` function returns no value.

In other words, `rand()` returns a pseudo-random sequence of integers between `0` and `RAND_MAX`. The sequence is not random, it is predictable for every value passed to `srand()`, including if `srand()` is never called.

In order to try and get different sequences for successive runs of the program, `srand()` can be called with a rapidly varying value, such as the return value of `clock()`. Note that calling `srand(time(NULL))` will produce the same sequence for multiple runs of the program during the same second.

Comment: Your answer contradict the documentation: "If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is called with a seed value of 1."

Comment: @user515430: you are absolutely correct. the specification does not leave any space for randomness. Answer corrected.